# Filter records in a subform based on selected record in another subform

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, record, subform

I have two subforms of a table each one in Access both in datasheet view. The tables have a field in common to link them.

I want to filter the second subform when a field of the first one is selected. The query is very simple, but the rest of the script I don't know how to do it because I don't know nothing about write code in Access...

```
SELECT *

FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.CP_ID_CLIENT = t2.CP_ID

WHERE t2.CP_ID = (record selected of the first subform)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are the two forms linked?

Answer (score 0):

on subform 1: Set an on click vba event on the field that would trigger a refresh. set it to requery the second subform, something like;

```
forms!mainform!subform2.requery
```

on subform 2:

Set the datasource of the second subform to contain all data. Then in the datasource set a filter criteria on the field that matches the field selected in the first subform.  something like;

```
forms!mainform!subform1.form!fieldname
```

now when you click the field in subform1 it refreshes the subform 2, when the subform 2 is refreshed it looks what record is selected an what the value of the fieldname is and uses it as the filter.